# Fill a table cell with a link with hover color

Tags: colors, html-table, hover, cell

I am trying to have the entire table cell be a link that changes background color on hover.
It used to be simple with Javascript but I can't get that to work any more.
Now I can't get this to work either.
The entire table cell is clickable (good) but no color change (bad).
What am I doing wrong?

```
<table width=980 height=100 style="margin:10px;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%" height="40" style="vertical-align:middle;border:5px solid #899e7d;">
<a class="ClickCell" href="who.php">About Us</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

.ClickCell {
  color:#cf9654;
  cursor:hand;
  display:block;
  font-size:32px;
  height:100%;
  margin: -10em;
  padding: 10em;
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100%;
}

.ClickCell:hover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}

.ClickCell:hover a {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the you are calling an anchor tag within the ClickCell object. The anchor tag *is* the ClickCell object. Instead, add a class to the cell and just change the cell directly, because the anchor tag within is an inline element anyway. For example:

```
td.HoverCell:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

JSFiddle of the solution: 
http://jsfiddle.net/D2bA3/

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and it almost works.  Now the entire cell is still clickable, but it only turns yellow when I'm hovering over the actual text of the link ... which is only 50% of the cell.